# Hibernate: Need to save the same object twice within the transaction

Tags: hibernate

I need to save the same object twice within transaction, but hibernate always have only one sql update, any way to do it?
Here is the code:

```
....
session.beginTransaction();
Student s = session.get(Student.class, id);

// (1) first save 
s.setSequenceNum(10);
session.saveOrUpdate(s);

// (2) second save
s.setSequenceNum(9);
session.saveOrUpdate(s);  // save again

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

hibernate will ignore the first one, and only have one sql update for the second. How can i let hibernate do both of the two sql update? I need this because it is the requirement in our project.

Comment: how do you know that it ignored the first one and only updated the second? Since looking in the database alone, you can not figure out that it has ignore your first request...

Comment: In any case this is redundant since the second update would overwrite the first. The only reason I can see for this if there is some sort of db trigger that must be executed

Comment: And why do you want two updates??

Answer (score 9):

`saveOrUpdate` is completely unnecessary for an attached instance. Hibernate will automatically persist the state of an attached object

- at the end of the transaction
- when executing a query whose result might depend on the new state of the object
- when calling flush explicitely on the session

An attached object is an object that you have retrieved from the session (from a call to get, load, or from a query), or that you have made persistent via persist, save, update or merge (in this latter case, the passed object is not attached, but the returned object is).

Then why is `saveOrUpdate` useful? It's useful to make a transient or detached object persistent, i.e. an object which is not attached to a session, either because it's new, or because it was attached previously, but became detached when the session closed.

The idea of Hibernate is to flush the modified state (i.e. to execute an update SQL query) only when it's necessary, at the latest possible time. This way, it can avoid unnecessary updates and thus make the code more efficient. Your first update is unnecessary, unless you're doing a native SQL query in the same transaction between the two updates. Why would you want the intermediate state to be persisted?

Comment: yes, it's true, i do need the first update, since the db has a unique index on the column "sequence_num", there already have "1,2,...8,9", and I want to swap 8 and 9. so what I did is: 1) 8 -> 10, 2) 9 - > 8, 3) 10 - > 9

Comment: Ah, OK. Then just flush the session once you have set the new value. No need for saveOrUpdate. An easier way would be to define this constraint as a deferred constraint. A deferred constrained is only checked at the end of a transaction, and not each time a new value is set.

Answer (score 4):

Try session.flush() after the first update or set session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.Always) before the first update. Remember that setFlushmode will affect the whole session if it is being reused after the transaction

Comment: Thanks, it can resolved my problem, one more question, if i set session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.Always), will this impact the performance? I mean it will become slower or not.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html
you would be performing more sql queries to the db so must likely it will be slower.